# Rescheduling an interview due to surgery email

Tags: interviewing, internship

I was recently diagnosed with appendicitis 1 day before the interview due to a stomach bug and have to get immediate surgery. Is this a good email to send out to the recruiter:

> Dear ___,
>
> I hope you are doing well. I apologize for the short notice, but I was unexpectedly diagnosed with appendicitis yesterday which requires a minor surgery scheduled for today. The time of recovery is of 2 days. Would it be possible to reschedule the interview next week on Monday, Tuesday (Anytime after before 2PM), Wednesday, Thursday, or Friday? Again I am very sorry for any inconvenience this causes.
>
> Sincerely

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: The day before - probably a call would be better.

Comment: I don't have the this HR's phone number. The first person that called me handed it off to some other HR to ask me times I am available so email is the only optionm.

Comment: I'd give yourself more than 2 days for recovery. I had a "minor" surgery last year where they told me it would be just a few days to recover (with a job interview scheduled during that time to boot!) and it took me well over a week before I was functional again, let alone in a shape where I could do well in an interview. Don't short your recovery time!

Answer (score 6):

Probably too much information.

Just say that you have a hospital appointment that can't move and a recovery time afterwards.  There's no need for any details at all.

You don't even need to mention the recovery time, just state the days you feel you can schedule for.

Comment: But shoudn't I tell them what? Isn't hospital appointment too vague?

Comment: You should probably point out (in some way) that it's a new issue, so you don't seem like someone who's bad at planning. One potential problem with being vague is that it might appear that you're regularly sick, given that they don't have much information to work with.

Comment: @Dukeling Exactly what I was thinking too! I don't want it to seem like I have a regular problem. I added some more information do you think that is better?

Comment: @Dukeling It's a recruiter the OP is speaking with.  It might be different if it was a manager, but recruiters won't care.  They just want to place the vacancy that's up on their screen.

Comment: You may want to consider that such vagueness could end up sounding evasive or shady

Comment: I don't think it'll be questioned.  But that's just my experience.

Comment: I think appendicitis is a "good" illness in the sense that it's well defined and short-term. Better to name it than to leave it open. Everyone will understand.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to include this level of detail. It isn't going to help you.

> Dear _____,
>
> I apologize for the short notice but I have had a personal emergency arise that requires immediate attention and will have me unavailable for several days. Can we reschedule to the middle of next week?  Again I am very sorry for any inconvenience this causes.
>
> Sincerely, You

Then, if possible, follow up with a phone call to ensure they've received it. On the phone, you do not need to disclose the nature of the personal emergency, just that there is one.

If the recruiter gets pushy about it and wants more detail, hold the line of "it's a personal situation and I would rather not disclose details." If you continue to feel pressure, maybe mention that it's medical in nature and they should back off at that point.

Comment: I don't mind saying the surgery thought I think it makes more sense to add that in correct?

Comment: "Immediate attention" implies that this is serious, which may result in getting dropped from the interview process.  It's best to keep things as light in details as possible.

Comment: Don't give up information (especially medical information) that isn't necessary, IMHO. When you get to the interview next week, maybe you could say "I apologize if I seem uncomfortable sitting for this long, I had my appendix out last week."

Comment: I like this.  How long a recovery time are you anticipating, incidentally? A colleague recently had his removed and he was off work for a full 4 weeks.  You may want to give yourself more time to recuperate.  Good luck, btw!

Comment: @snow I disagree - it indicates that there isn't room to negotiate moving it to another time.

Comment: Is this too light in natures and doesn't seem important: "I hope you are doing well. I apologize for the short notice, but I was unexpectedly diagnosed with appendicitis yesterday which requires a minor surgery scheduled for today. The time recovery time is of 2 days."